# CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH - SQL Server 2008 (Not the one from IINFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I know that if you do: 
`select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` you'll be able to see the column called `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH`; but I don't want to get that column from this table because I cannot uniquely JOIN this table with say `sys.columns` OR `sys.tables`.

So here's my question:

Is there a way to get `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` from any table inside the `sys` database?

In other words, is there any `SELECT` statement you can run on the `sys.SOME_TABLE` so that it would return to you the `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` from `SOME_TABLE`?

Again, I cannot use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` database at all; so please do NOT respond saying "there's a table inside INFORMATION_SCHEMA that will give you CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH".

`CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` needs to come from the `sys` database please.

Thanks to all for helping.

Comment: `sys.types`? join to `sys.columns` on `user_type_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `sys.types` table has `max_length`. This gives the maximum definable length for the type. You can join on to `sys.columns` via `user_type_id`.

In this situation, `sys.columns.max_length` gives the length the table column was defined at. So, for a `varchar(30)`, this would be 30. `sys.types.max_length`, however would give 8000, as the maximum definable length for `varchar`.